# Minimal generating set for $C_6$

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

Given a regular n-gon. Let r be rotation of it by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ radians. Then $C_n$ = {$e,r,r^2,...,r^{n-1}$}

I have to find all minimal generating sets of $C_6$. I see that r is needed for minimal set. But book says it has minimal sets of two elements also. I am thinking about horizontal translation in upper and lower side of hexagon but not sure

Comment: How about $r^k$ alone, for any $k$ that has no factors in common with $n$ ? What would be the least value of $t$ such that $(r^k)^t=r^k$ ?

Comment: Wouldnot $t=6$
 suffice?

Comment: It would indeed, but for some values of $k$, a lower value of $t$ might also suffice. Try some examples: Take $n=6$, say, and for each $k$ between 0 and 5 inclusive, compute the sequence of powers of $r^k$, remembering to reduce modulo $n$.

Comment: Keep going until you reach $r^k$ again, not $r$.

Comment: i see that various powers of $r^2$ generate {$e,r^2,r^4$}

Comment: Yes. Now do the same for the other values of k.

Comment: various powers of $r^5$ generate all elements. And various powers of $r^3$ generates {$r^3, e,$ }, various powers of r^4 generate {$r^2,r^4$}

Comment: What can you say about the values of k for which r^k generates the whole group, and why ?

Comment: Only $r^5$ and $r$ generates whole group as far i can see. i think it is because of modulo 6. Modulo 6 affects $r^2, r^4, r^3$ as much but not as much as former two..not sure

Comment: @Simon i have noticed something that $(5,6)=1$, so we have $ 5m+6n=1$. Writing as $r ^ {5m+6n} = r $ (not sure if how this is possible, if at all). $r^{5m} r^{6n} =  r$. Since $r^{6n} =  e$
.. So $(r^5)^{m} = r $. not sure where it leads to

Comment: You're heading in the right direction. Try ti predict which ks will work for n=18 for example.

Comment: @Simon In case of $n=18$ , $k=5$ generates the whole group

Comment: And which other values of k ? Exactly which ones work and which ones don't ? What is the rule for an arbitrary $n$ ? After figuring that out, you should think about generating sets that have more than one element, as in   Siddharth's answer.

Comment: @Simon $5,7,11,13,17$ works. Any for multiple elements in generating set it would be those elements who are not powers of one another

Comment: @Simon please continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the generating sets can be $\{r\}$ alone. Another one could be $\{r^{2},r^{3}\}$ i.e., take two elements such that one does not lie in the subgroup generated by another, then the set containing these two elements can act as generating set.
Making Cayley digraphs can help a lot in such cases.

Comment: How can your set generate r

Comment: That's for you to think about. Use the definition of generating set.

Comment: How can Cayley diagram help? I have made it Cayley diagram for cyclic group

Comment: Suppose the digraph is connected i.e. we can get from any vertex g to any vertex h where g and h are in the group by travelling along consecutive edges then every equation gx=h has a solution. Now, since the edges are nothing but ways of denoting the elements of the generator set, se can generate the entire group using the generators and their combinations

Comment: This happens to be the case for C6 (or Z6).